# CakePHP 3 debug session timeout

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

We moved our application to a new server and now the session is expiring too soon (not sure about exact hours) for the logged in users. We tried many things to find out why the session is expiring in a production environment but until now we are unsuccessful. We want to put the expiration for 20 days.

**Stuff we tried:**

This is the current configuration:

```
'Session' => [
  'defaults' => 'php',
  'cookie' => 'MYAPPHO',
  'timeout'=> 80320, // in min
  'ini' => [
      'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 1728000, // in sec
      'session.cookie_lifetime' => 1728000
  ]
]
```

We also tried to set the

```
'defaults' => 'cache'
```

and to set the values in .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 1728000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1728000
php_value session.cache_expire 1728000
```

but the behavior is the same.

We also made some debugging in the Network\Session::_timedOut() but is ok, is never expiring for that reason.

Is there any way to debug more and find out what is causing the session to expire?

Comment: Use browser tools to check the details of the cookie, making sure that it is set for the correct expiry?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Cookie is correctly expiring in 20 days.

Comment: Check if you are actually loading the correct configuration. Use phpinfo() in one of your views and check if the session variables are the correct ones.

Answer (score 3):

Hackers would be delighted to have sessions never expire, because then any stolen session ID would become a permanent key to unlock your web application.

More details on why what you've tried with `session.gc_maxlifetime` and `session.cookie_lifetime` didn't work can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/5675325).

Anyways, you can do it by setting the value of [session.gc_probability](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) to 0 before starting the session.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to restart your application server. Some times server cache behaves weirdly.Hope this will resolve your issue.